# Uncaught Error: Ziggy error: 'x' parameter is required for route 'y' even if 'x' parameter has been provided

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I keep receiving this error.
My app has vue component for searching product:

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="searchProduct">
        <input
            placeholder="Search"
            v-model="form.q"
            type="search"/>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: this.$inertia.form({
                _method: "get",
                q: '',
            }),
        };
    },
    methods: {
        searchProduct() {
            this.form.get(route('search.product', {q : this.q}), {
                errorBag: "validate_q",
                preserveScroll: true,
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

And in my web.php

```
// Search product
Route::get('search/{q}', [ProductController::class, 'search'])->name('search.product');
```

I wonder why this error happens? I use Laravel jetstream + inertiajs

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missed a reference to your form:

```js
// replace this
this.form.get(route('search.product', {q : this.q}), {

// with this
this.form.get(route('search.product', {q : this.form.q}), {
```

Also, be aware that you're passing `q` as route param and ALSO as a query string param.

```js
form: this.$inertia.form({
   _method: "get",
   q: '', // this will be passed as a query string param
}),
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. But it is not working.